# Can an attacker spoof content provider, backup manager or wallpaper manager in Android?

Tags: penetration-test, android, mobile, exploit-development

We need a backup of SMSes, apps, device settings, wallpapers and contacts of the device through our designed app.

So, is it possible for an attacker to spoof, tamper, impersonate source data (SMSes, device setting, contacts etc.) though a wallpaper manager, content provider, or backup manager?